# Linux Lib to use with NDK on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I try to run a working Linux library with NDK on an Android device. The Android Studio tells me always that is everything is fine but finally the app crash on the device. The only reason in my eyes is that the lib is using some decencies that are not working on Android.

I made a ldd and the output is:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffef7deb000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007fd8ece81000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd8ecaf8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd8ec75a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd8ec542000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd8ec151000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd8ebf4d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd8ebd2e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd8ebb26000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd8ed754000)
```

I think all are common Linux libraries and have to work in Android with NDK. Anybody here with a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Android is Linux, but it's not *GNU*/Linux. That library is built for a GNU system. You need to rebuild that library, as well as libasound, with the NDK.

As for the other libraries, you don't need to build those, but they're probably worth a bit of explanation:

- linux-vdso: Not actually a library :)
- libstdc++: The NDK has libc++.so.
- libgcc: NDK has it, used automatically
- libc, libm, libdl: NDK has these, although they're bionic and not glibc, so you may need to make some source changes.
- libpthread, librt: Not necessary on Android, as they're just a part of libc
- ld-linux: Also not a library, Android will uses /system/bin/linker64